# How can I change permissions of a file on a ftp server using apache commons net ftp?

Tags: java, apache-commons-net

If have a list of ftp files from a server, how can I change the permission on one of these files?

If someone can point me to a tutorial or show me an example I would be grateful. I have figured out how to change the permission in the file but not how to make the change permanent on the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you explain a bit what exactly have you figured out, and in what way are those changes temporary?

Comment: ftpFile.setPermission(FTPFile.WORLD_ACCESS, FTPFile.EXECUTE_PERMISSION, boolean);

By doing this on a ftpfile it is changed in my app, but not changed on the server. Any suggestions?

Comment: well, I did some stuff with commons-net ftp, but never changed the permissions... Of the top of my head, maybe you need to do/set something additional with the users and the groups, looks like something related to that? Running the Linux server?

Comment: From the library [docs](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html#setPermission(int, int, boolean)) for the `setPermission` method: _Set if the given access group (one of the _ACCESS constants) has the given access permission (one of the _PERMISSION constants) to the file._

Comment: Exactly, this is what I'm doing. So I have the nine combinations with USER GROUP & WORLD with READ WRITE & EXECUTE. But after the change is made to the file its like its just locally and not changed at the server. I'm trying with a hostgator server right now.

Comment: You are right, we're missing something here, I just looked into the source of this method , and all it does is to set the value in a field 2d array: `_permissions[access][permission] = value;` Indeed it looks like this has to be written back to server.

Comment: I've tried the ftpClient.completePendingCommand() wich more or less freezes everything. It feels like it should be this method, or something similar but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the permission of a file can be achieved by using this in the directory where the file or directory is:

```
ftpClient.sendSiteCommand("chmod " + "755" + " example.html");
```

NOTE:
Why no one knows how setPermission() in FTPFile works is a mystery to me. Because it seems like a better way instead of using command line for setting permission of a ftpFile in apache commons net library!

Comment: It just doesnt work, there is no way to put a FTPFILE in the client or just and UPDATE option for the file thats why :(